# iconv in Mac OS X 10.7.3 does nothing

Tags: macos, unix, encoding, iconv

I am trying to convert a php file (client.php) from utf-8 to iso-8859-1 and the following command does nothing on the file:

> iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 client.php

Upon execution the original file contents are displayed.

In fact, when I check for the file's encoding after executing **iconv** with:

> file -I client.php

The same old utf-8 is shown:

> client.php:           text/x-php; charset=utf-8

Comment: Are there any non-ASCII characters in the file where the encoding would actually make a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iconv utility shall convert the encoding of characters in file from one codeset to another and write the results to **standard output**.

Here's a solution :
Write stdout to a temporary file and rename the temporary file

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO_8859-1 client.php > client_temp.php && mv -f client_temp.php client.php
```

Comment: Hey @jackjr300 !! It worked!! IMHO, there should be a flag in iconv that allowed to overwrite the input file. Just an opinion. I will be aware the next time I read that results are written to standard output.

Comment: @jackjr300 Could you help me with this problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573329/iconv-in-macos-doesnt-convert-file-from-us-ascii-to-utf-8

Answer (score 1):

ASCII, UTF-8 and ISO-8859 are 100% identical encodings for the lowest 128 characters. If your file only contains characters in that range (which is basically the set of characters you find on a common US English keyboard), there's no difference between these encodings.

My guess what's happening: A plain text file has no associated encoding meta data. You cannot know the encoding of a plain text file just by looking at it. What the `file` utility is doing is simply giving its best guess, and since there's no difference it prefers to tell you the file is UTF-8 encoded, which technically it may well be.

Comment: My file contains some spanish characters that are not in the ASCII set. In fact, I noticed there was something wrong with the encoding when I rendered my file using: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="iso-8859-1">`. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jackjr300 with the following One-Liner you can do it for all php files in the current folder:

```
for filename in *.php; do  iconv -f ISO_8859-1 -t UTF-8 $filename > temp_$filename && mv -f ./temp_$filename ./$filename; done
```